# using Jquery textfill to keep text inside div

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains user-entered copy an a form control that lets the user choose the font size for the copy in the div. I want to only allow then to scale the font size up until the copy reach the max width or height of the dev. I do not want the copy to go outside of the div.

I have tried every combination I can think of and none worked.

```js
$('.sign-header-font-size').on('change', function() {

  var topFontSize = $('#alg_wc_pif_local_2_bubble').text()

  $('.message-header span').css('font-size', topFontSize + "px");

  $('.message-header span').textfill({ //auto size text in signs
    maxFontPixels: 40,
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-textfill@0.6.0/source/jquery.textfill.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="alg_wc_pif_local_2">Font Size</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input form="cart" min="2" max="100" step="1" class="sign-header-font-size" value="12" type="range" name="alg_wc_pif_local_2" data-min_qty="1" id="alg_wc_pif_local_2" placeholder="Font Size">
        </input>
        <span class="alg_wc_pif_range_max">100</span>
        <span class="alg_wc_pif_range_bubble" style="float:right;" id="alg_wc_pif_local_2_bubble">57</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="message-wrapper" class="message-wrapper">
  <div id="message-header" class="message-header">
    <span>YOUR TEXT</span>
  </div>

  <div id="message-footer" class="message-footer">
    <span>MORE TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no element with that class in your markup. Please update the demo above so it shows your problem accurately.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. an `<input` is an Empty content model element thus do not need and cannot have a closing tag `</input>` it must be of this form: `<input />` if you need xml compliance ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html sometimes called void elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with not even needing the plugin OR jQuery you can do it like this.

I set the value using values from ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements and plug that in dynamically.

Note you probably want to make the element size using CSS which you do not have but perhaps `height: 4em;` or some such so I used `6em;`

I added some borders just to show what is where.

```js
document.querySelector('.sign-header-font-size').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.message-wrapper');
  const headerText = wrapper.querySelector('.message-header span');
  const footer = wrapper.querySelector('.message-footer');
  const fonterFont = Math.ceil(footer.clientHeight) / 2;
  const marg = Math.abs(wrapper.offsetHeight - wrapper.scrollHeight);
  const maxPixels = wrapper.scrollHeight - (footer.offsetHeight + marg + fonterFont);
  let sliderValue = document.querySelector('#alg_wc_pif_local_2').value;
  sliderValue = sliderValue > maxPixels ? maxPixels : sliderValue;
  const bub = document.querySelector('#alg_wc_pif_local_2_bubble').textContent = sliderValue;

  headerText.style.fontSize = (sliderValue - marg) * 1 + "px";
});
```

```css
.message-wrapper {
  height: 6em;
  border: solid lime 1px;
}

.message-footer {
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="alg_wc_pif_local_2">Font Size</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input form="cart" min="2" max="100" step="1" class="sign-header-font-size" value="12" type="range" name="alg_wc_pif_local_2" data-min_qty="1" id="alg_wc_pif_local_2" placeholder="Font Size" />
      <span class="alg_wc_pif_range_max">100</span>
      <span class="alg_wc_pif_range_bubble" style="float:right;" id="alg_wc_pif_local_2_bubble">57</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="message-wrapper" class="message-wrapper">
  <div id="message-header" class="message-header">
    <span>YOUR TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <div id="message-footer" class="message-footer">
    <span>MORE TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```